# Lye from human ashes?

Tags: ph

I have a friend who requested to be cremated when they died and their ashes planted with a tree.  I am a bit concerned that the ashes will not be good for the health of the tree.

Will ashes from human remains create an alkaline solution when mixed with water?

Comment: Google burial pods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Human bones would likely be chemically similar to any other mammal bones. It is sold as fertilizer (bone meal), primarily a source for phosphorus. It will also contain other elements like calcium. It should not be a problem, especially after mixing with soil.